# Azure Logic Apps SMTP Connector {"code":"BadRequest","message":"Http request failed: the timeout was reached."}

Tags: azure, smtp, gmail, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to create a simple hello world logic app that e-mails myself.

I added the SMTP Connector and filled in the properties with the following for Google:

Server: smtp.google.com

Port: 465 (587 was tried unsuccessfully as well)

UserAccount: xtenxxx@gmail.com

Password: xpassxx

SSL: True

Then once the API is created, i used:

To: xtenxxx@gmail.com

Subject: Test

Body: Test

I run it manually and receive this error:

{"code":"BadRequest","message":"Http request failed: the timeout was reached."}

I am able to use other connectors such as Twitter and Dropbox without issue. so I am assuming it must be the API parameters I am putting in.

Any guidance would be appreciated.  Thanks

Edited to add the CodeView:

`{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2014-12-01-preview/workflowdefinition.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "/subscriptions/49c83dfe-f987-4e2e-8b23-c6ceb2c4855e/resourceGroups/Default-Web-EastUS/providers/Microsoft.AppService/apiApps/SMTPConnector/token": {
            "type": "String",
            "defaultValue": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJtc25hbWUiOiJFTUEuUmVzb3VyY2VQcm92aWRlciIsImZ1bGxyb3ciOiJhbGwiLCJkYmciOiJEZWZhdWx0LVdlYi1FYXN0VVM0OWM4M2RmZWY5ODc0ZTJlOGIyM2M2Y2ViMmM0ODU1ZSw1MzE3ODQxNDIiLCJ2ZXIiOiIzIiwidWlkIjoic2lkOjE0MzUwNzU5MjE3MzMiLCJpc3MiOiJ1cm46bWljcm9zb2Z0OndpbmRvd3MtYXp1cmU6enVtbyIsImF1ZCI6InVybjptaWNyb3NvZnQ6d2luZG93cy1henVyZTp6dW1vIiwibmJmIjoxNDM1MDc1OTIyfQ.VK1gtDPgaxaaEhp_9AZYtVR2BD8gLrDaKKcYyFpg_lk",
            "metadata": {
                "token": {
                    "name": "/subscriptions/49c83dfe-f987-4e2e-8b23-c6ceb2c4855e/resourcegroups/default-web-eastus/providers/Microsoft.AppService/apiapps/smtpconnector/token"
                }
            }
        },
        "/subscriptions/49c83dfe-f987-4e2e-8b23-c6ceb2c4855e/resourcegroups/default-web-eastus/providers/Microsoft.AppService/apiapps/twitterconnector/token": {
            "defaultValue": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJtc25hbWUiOiJFTUEuUmVzb3VyY2VQcm92aWRlciIsImZ1bGxyb3ciOiJhbGwiLCJkYmciOiJEZWZhdWx0LVdlYi1FYXN0VVM0OWM4M2RmZWY5ODc0ZTJlOGIyM2M2Y2ViMmM0ODU1ZSw1MzE3ODQxNDIiLCJ2ZXIiOiIzIiwidWlkIjoic2lkOjE0MzUwNzYxMDIwMTQiLCJpc3MiOiJ1cm46bWljcm9zb2Z0OndpbmRvd3MtYXp1cmU6enVtbyIsImF1ZCI6InVybjptaWNyb3NvZnQ6d2luZG93cy1henVyZTp6dW1vIiwibmJmIjoxNDM1MDc2MTAzfQ.GSyp45LKqNsN_vi1FQlYBj8h_yAybXQsX8WKSXTcvNc",
            "type": "String",
            "metadata": {
                "token": {
                    "name": "/subscriptions/49c83dfe-f987-4e2e-8b23-c6ceb2c4855e/resourcegroups/default-web-eastus/providers/Microsoft.AppService/apiapps/twitterconnector/token"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "triggers": {
        "recurrence": {
            "type": "Recurrence",
            "recurrence": {
                "frequency": "Hour",
                "interval": 1
            }
        }
    },
    "actions": {
        "smtpconnector": {
            "type": "ApiApp",
            "inputs": {
                "apiVersion": "2015-01-14",
                "host": {
                    "id": "/subscriptions/49c83dfe-f987-4e2e-8b23-c6ceb2c4855e/resourcegroups/default-web-eastus/providers/Microsoft.AppService/apiapps/smtpconnector",
                    "gateway": "https://default-web-eastus49c83dfef9874e2e8b23c6ceb2c4855e.azurewebsites.net"
                },
                "operation": "SendEmail",
                "parameters": {
                    "emailDetails": {
                        "To": "ctenden@gmail.com",
                        "Subject": "Test",
                        "Body": "Test"
                    }
                },
                "authentication": {
                    "type": "Raw",
                    "scheme": "Zumo",
                    "parameter": "@parameters('/subscriptions/49c83dfe-f987-4e2e-8b23-c6ceb2c4855e/resourcegroups/default-web-eastus/providers/Microsoft.AppService/apiapps/smtpconnector/token')"
                }
            },
            "conditions": []
        }
    },
    "outputs": {}
}`

Comment: We need to see more code to help you?

Comment: The problem is with a line of code that you failed to paste ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me with a gmail.com  on Logic Apps when I use port 587 instead of 465.

Comment: Unfortunately 587 failed as well.   I also tried going in to the API Application and setting it to Public (Anonymous) from Internal.  No luck there either.

Comment: Ah yes I'm starting to see the issue you are. Most likely due to some of Gmails automated methods for filtering SMTP points to reduce spam (Reverse DNS and such).  The hard part is from looking online it looks like sometimes Gmail will just 'ignore' you instead of returning an error code.  I would try to use a different SMTP endpoint for now - but let me know.

Comment: I created a SendGrid instance and used it successfully first try.